# No public constructors in API

Tags: android, api

Sometimes I see the description of some classes in Android API aren't quite comprehensive (or I can't read it properly). For example
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

There are no any information about public constructor over there, no information on how should I create an instance of this class. I searched and found that I have to use `getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)` method to instantiate it. How would I ever know that I need to use this method? Why this isn't included in API description?

So my question - where should I look for this kind of information (instead of googling the answers).

Comment: Because you're not constructing one, you're retrieving the service that already exists and using it. I do agree, there should be a notation in the documentation to get an instance using getSystemService though.

Comment: @A.Noob Agreed.  The reference is there from the other direction as a @see also in the Context class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#VIBRATOR_SERVICE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Type `Vibrator` into the search box in the upper-right corner of most developer.android.com pages.

Step #2: Choose the second search result, whose preview snippet includes:

> Use with getSystemService(String) to retrieve a Vibrator for interacting with the vibration hardware.

You are correct that the documentation is lacking in various areas.